# How to bring forward div element inside overflow auto?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scenario where I need overflow auto for the scrollbar but I want one of the elements inside to pop out. I made a demo which shows what I'm currently getting. I would like that blue box to not cut behind while still having overflow auto on my main container.

I could only get it to kind of work by making the blue box `position: fixed` but that way I'm unable to align it besides my red div.

How should this be done?

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 25px 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans,
        Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #091c32;
    color: #fff;
}
.scroll {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 400px;

    overflow: auto;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 205px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.innerBox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: blue;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

After applying the css trick @chazsolo suggested, I discovered that I still have an issue of the blue box not following the red boxes on scroll.

But furthermore it made me realize that there's even a bigger issue to fix; which is being able to hide those blue boxes that are underneath the `.scroll` div.

Here's updated code:

```css
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans,
        Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    background: #091c32;
    color: #fff;
}

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.scroll {
    border: 5px solid #000;
    padding: 0 10px;
    max-width: 250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 400px;

    overflow: auto;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 205px;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    background: red;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: static;
}

.innerBox {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background: blue;
    // top: 0;
    // left: 0;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">World</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="innerBox">World</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't nest the blue `div` elements inside of the `scroll` element. Position them where you want them instead.

Comment: There's a [CSS Tricks article on this very problem](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) related to drop-down menus which I believe you may be able to reverse engineer for your case

Comment: They have used JS to resolve the problem in the article chazsolo has linked. This is not possible with pure CSS. With JS you can do [something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/r5pfecm4/1/), but as you can see, there will be more problems to resolve. In the fiddle the parents of the blue boxes are statically positioned, that makes `body` being the offset parent for the blue boxes. The position will still be relative to their real parent untill you explicitly set the position. JS part sets the vertical position, but the horizontal position is not touched, and it stays fixed to the parent.

Comment: Thank you @Teemu, this helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a useable solution to this, if it's ever needed.

```js
const scrollBox = document.querySelector('.scroll');
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.innerBox');
scrollBox.addEventListener('scroll', e => {
  boxes.forEach(box => {
    const top = box.parentElement.offsetTop;
    const bHH = box.offsetHeight / 2;
    box.style.top = `${top - e.target.scrollTop + bHH}px`;
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0 25px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  background: #091c32;
  color: #fff;
}

.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.scroll {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 250px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 205px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.innerBox {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  background: blue;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>

<div class="container">
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="innerBox">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="innerBox">World</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="innerBox">Hello</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="innerBox">World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam non dapibus risus.</p>
```

Thank you to everyone who helped :)